# Is there any better way to send information to child view?

Tags: swift

I have a view controller which has a child view. I want to convey information from the view to the child view. To do so, I did this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "visualize", sender: self)
    invoiceNumber = indexPath.row
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! PreviewViewController
    vc.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber
}
```

But the problem is that the value of invoiceNumber is not updated on the first iteration but on the second. I tried to see what the problem was and found that "invoiceNumber = indexPath.row" runs after "vc.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber". Please help ! Thanks

Here is the code of printing :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var invoiceNumber: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print(invoiceNumber)
    }
}
```

Sorry I have mistaken :

```
    var customerData: [[customerInformation]] = []
    var itemsData: [[Item]] = []
    var totalData: [TotalInformation] = []

    var invoiceNumber = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let tabBar = tabBarController as! baseTabBarController
        customerData = tabBar.customerData
        itemsData = tabBar.itemsData
        totalData = tabBar.totalData
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return customerData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let invoiceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "invoice", for: indexPath) as! invoiceTableViewCell
        invoiceCell.textLabel?.text = (customerData[indexPath.row][0]).input
        invoiceCell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Invoice n°" + String(indexPath.row)
        invoiceCell.totalLabel.text = (totalData[indexPath.row]).total
        return invoiceCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let tabBar = tabBarController as! baseTabBarController
            tabBar.customerData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            //itemData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tabBar.totalData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            customerData = tabBar.customerData
            itemsData = tabBar.itemsData
            totalData = tabBar.totalData
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        invoiceNumber = indexPath.row
        print(invoiceNumber, "yes")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "visualize", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! PreviewViewController
        vc.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber
    }        
}
```

It is the "vc.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber" which comes before the "invoiceNumber = indexPath.row" as I tried to change the value of invoiceNumber a variable in the view and print out the value in the child view and if showed its value first (I tested -1).

I added the Preview view controller which receives the invoiceNumber :

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class PreviewViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webPreview: UIWebView!

    var invoiceComposer: InvoiceComposer!
    var HTMLContent: String!

    var invoiceNumber: Int = -1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print(invoiceNumber)
        createInvoiceAsHTML()
    }

    func createInvoiceAsHTML() {
        invoiceComposer = InvoiceComposer()
        if let tabBar = tabBarController as? baseTabBarController {
            if let invoiceHTML = invoiceComposer.renderInvoice(invoiceNumber: String(invoiceNumber), invoiceDate: "", recipientInfo: tabBar.customerData[invoiceNumber][0].input, items: tabBar.itemsData[invoiceNumber], totalAmount: tabBar.totalData[invoiceNumber].total) {

                   webPreview.loadHTMLString(invoiceHTML, baseURL: NSURL(string: invoiceComposer.pathToInvoiceHTMLTemplate!)! as URL)
                   HTMLContent = invoiceHTML
            }
        }
        else {
            print("tabBarController is not of type baseTabBarController or either nil ")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved ?

Comment: Nope it isn't resolved

Comment: Now whats the problem after updating the order of statements for performSegue and updating of invoiceNumber ?

Comment: The "vc.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber" runs before the "invoiceNumber = indexPath.row" but I want the inverse.

Comment: With this order 
1) `invoiceNumber = indexPath.row` 
2) `performSegue(withIdentifier: "visualize", sender: self)`
It will run correctly.

Comment: does it resolved now ?

Comment: @NajeeburRehman That's exactly what I said in my answer.

Comment: Yes @Frankenstein you have mentioned it right but don't know why he still not getting the updated value. May be he is observing the wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of execution, like this:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    invoiceNumber = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "visualize", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: perfect answer dude !

Comment: In which method of the class are you trying to print? Add the code in your question.

Comment: @m4thus4n You are setting the invoice number as the indexPath.row which starts from 0. So, if you select the first row you will get 0. Try setting it to another value like a 100 and see if you get it right.

Comment: I clicked on the second row so it should be 1. And to test, I set the value to -1.

Comment: @m4thus4n Are you sure you aren't doing anything else that is affecting the execution in the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

I should have connected the segue from the view controller to the child view and not from the cell to the child view.